# Import a Sound into Flash CS5 with a relative path

Tags: audio, flash-cs5

I'm looking to import an mp3 into Flash CS5, but Flash is only letting me import the file with an absolute path. Is there a way I can import the mp3 into Flash with a path of "../sounds/file.mp3" so that the Update feature still works if I move the outside directory around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on my Mac version of cs5, paths are absolute when the sounds are first imported, but then change to relative once the file is saved. The containing folder can then be moved around and the link between asset and sound file remains intact.